# Refresh dropdown in parent, when user closes popu window

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, popup

I have a three step registration process, all on one page, the last of which requires the user to select a saved payment method or input a new one.

Obviously, I want to collect that new data over SSL. Step 2 of the process involves showing the user a Google map, and the GMaps API doesn't play nice with SSL.

My solution is to use a popup with a small "New Payment Method" page served via SSL. The user enters the info, and gives the new payment method a nicjname. When they click the submit button I use an ajax call to save the info to the database before closing the window.

My question is how do I update the parent page with the new method's nickname, so that the user can finish the registration process?

I'm using jQuery, so any solutions using jQuery would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the original window with opener using javascript, including calls to any function defined in that window.

For instance:

```
window.opener.addValue(newValue);
```

Should do what you want.